# What forces are causing the COM to align with the tail end of force vector?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A force F is continually acting on the end of a solid rod at a pivot point A  (see image below). The object causing that continual 'Force F' is attached to pivot point A and constrained to only move in the line of direction shown.

What forces are causing the center of mass (COM) to move in line with the tail end of the force vector F?

I understand that one can assume a ‘moment of a couple’ will be created about the COM,  but couples do not physically move the COM.  If that is the case, then is it force F causing the COM to move up and to the left?

But how can that be possible because there is no vertical force component for F?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider Newton's Second Law -
$$∑F = m a$$

What exactly does **a** mean here.It refers to acceleration of Centre of Mass of the system.In your question,when you use Newton's Second Law the acceleration term is of Centre of Mass and not that of A.

Get it?

Centre of Mass does not move up. Point A moves down.Centre of Mass moves in a straight horizontal line.

> Why does point A moves down?

This is because **F** provides necessary torque to do so.

Comment: Hi Tony -  I understand what you mean but in my example I meant making force F move in a straight line (as shown in the diagram ) and not allowing point A to move down. If that scenario , what forces will move the COM up?

Comment: Tony - look at this video below up to 6:01 and you will understand the scenario I'm talking about .    https://vimeo.com/158419250

Comment: To prevent A from moving down, an external vertical force must be applied.

Comment: @Dubious If you take A as your axis of rotation,then COM will rotate due to pseudo torque. This is perhaps what best fits your video.

Comment: @Dubious I have a suggestion. Try asking another question about how dynamics of golf work.

Comment: Hi Tony - that question is still a bit of a mystery because of something called a 'closed loop'. If one knew the answer and how pga pros swung their clubs , you'd be a millionaire. On reflection I think R.W Bird could be partially correct  but its not a vertical force at A (maybe a vertical component). I've never heard of a pseudo torque before.

Comment: Just read about pseudo torques/forces (imho - very non-intuitive) and I think I have an answer now. I'll try and publish it when I've got all my facts straight.

Comment: Attn Tony Stark:  How would you use the method of a pseudo torque?  Wouldn't that mean trying to change the 'force/rod system' into some inertial frame of reference? Then one would need to add 'pseudo forces ' to that system . Isn't that a more difficult method than the one used in my answer? Would you be able to describe a more elegant solution to my problem using pseudo torques?

Answer (score 0):

After much thought I think I have the answer but I had to go through various steps . Please see the diagrams below. For the COM to move up and align itself with force F it seems another force needs to be applied at point A to prevent it spinning around its centre of mass.

[image: STEPS 1-3]

[image]

[image]